# Что за отступ у нижнего края?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru-RU"><head></head>
    <body>  
        <a style="background: #000; width: 120px; display:block;">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill="#adadad2b"></circle>
                <path d="M17.9907,11.118c0.1191,1.6938,-0.1307,3.5067,-1.2318,4.8664c-1.5078,1.9407,-4.294,2.5102,-6.5601,1.749c-2.4056,-0.7902,-4.1546,-3.2133,-4.1023,-5.7525c-0.1191,-3.1377,2.6293,-6.0372,5.7699,-6.075c1.6008,-0.1365,3.158,0.4852,4.3696,1.4991c-0.4968,0.5462,-1.0023,1.0866,-1.5427,1.5921c-1.0662,-0.6479,-2.3504,-1.1418,-3.5967,-0.7031c-2.0105,0.5723,-3.2278,2.946,-2.484,4.9128c0.6159,2.054,3.1145,3.1813,5.0726,2.3184c1.0139,-0.3632,1.6822,-1.2987,1.9756,-2.3039c-1.1621,-0.0232,-2.3242,-0.0087,-3.4863,-0.0407c-0.0029,-0.6915,-0.0058,-1.38,-0.0029,-2.0715C14.1092,11.1064,16.05,11.1006,17.9907,11.118z" fill="#e05b49"></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Не понимаю что за отступ появляется у нижнего края? Он появляется тогда, когда в документ начинается с

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Как поправить?

Comment: там нету отступа ни какого

Comment: `display: inline-block` для svg

Comment: Элемент `<svg>` по умолчанию имеет `display: inline`, то есть, условно, считается символом, и этот отступ внизу — место под хвостики для букв p, д, y и прочих. Сделайте `display: block` и отступ пропадёт

Comment: Работает, спс...

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов `<!DOCTYPE html>` говорит о том, что система открывает файл формата html в нужной версии. Если изучить документацию, то выше написанный код показывает нам, что мы используем HTML 5.